TF accuracy metric wants a single value but gets a list of probabilities
I am performing a simple seq-to-seq transformer task. I have tried various loss and metrics but none are working. Currently, in model.compile() I am using these:
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
metrics=['accuracy'],

The input and final_layer output of the code is correct (batch_size, output_seq_length, output_vocab_size):
Sample input shape (encoder input): (18, 20)
Sample input shape (decoder input): (18, 100)
Model output shape: (18, 100, 200)
tf.Tensor([ 18 100 200], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)

Regardless, I get the error that it wants a single value:
InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 100
 [[{{node metrics/accuracy/Squeeze}}]]

All code is available in a relatively simple playground:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tfk518PwmrJEapxIQlOuiLmiTSfxREk3?usp=sharing
But here is some core code (I've tried all of the metrics and losses):
self.encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(args.problem_vocab_size, args.dim)
self.encoder_ffn = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(args.dim_ff, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(args.dim)
])

self.decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(args.solution_vocab_size, args.dim)
self.cross_attention = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=args.num_heads, key_dim=args.dim // args.num_heads)
self.decoder_ffn = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(args.dim_ff, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(args.dim)
])

self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(args.solution_vocab_size)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(args.learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy],
              run_eagerly=False)

model.fit(dataset, epochs=args.epochs, steps_per_epoch=args.num_batches)


I think that's an edge case of the sparse categorical accuracy metric. In a sequence data like this, you need your target to have 3 dimensions aswell.
So you need to change data creation step:
    def teacher_forcing_format(question, solution):
        return (question, solution), tf.expand_dims(solution, axis=-1)

That's how Keras expects the data format, not sure if that's documented. Here's the lines that were causing you trouble (probably) (source code).

Found out a solution though I still don't know why the original method doesn't work.  If I use sparse_categorical_crossentropy metric it works - though I believe this makes my accuracy less relevant as a metric for a seq-to-seq task.
